# Inconsistent implicit conversion behavior

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I encountered a case where I cannot understand the implicit conversion behavior in c++.
The code is the following:

```
template <bool b, int i, unsigned... us>
void foo() {}

template <int i, unsigned... us>
void foo() {return foo<false, i, us...>();}

int main()
{
    foo<true, -1, 0ul, 1ul, 2ul>(); // compiles with clang and gcc > 8 (gcc<=8 gives ambiguous function call)
    foo<true, +1, 0ul, 1ul, 2ul>(); // ambiguous function call error
    foo<-1, 0ul, 1ul, 3ul>(); // compiles with clang and gcc > 8 (gcc<=8 gives ambiguous function call)
    foo<+1, 0ul, 1ul, 3ul>(); // ambiguous function call error
}
```

For line 1 and 2 in `main()`, the compiler seems to implicitly convert `int` to `unsigned` only for positive integers (this is understandable but is there a rule for this?)

For line 3 and 4 in `main()`, the compiler seems to implicitly convert `int` to `bool` only for positive integers. I cannot understand why.

Background: Ideally, I want to get a similar construct to work which effectly leads to a default value for the `bool` template parameter. But because of the parameter pack and c++ implicit builtin conversions, this seems to be difficult.

Comment: _the compiler seems to implicitly cast int to bool only for positive integers. I cannot understand why_ Makes sense to me - you are (implicitly) casting an integer _constant_ and the compiler knows that `-1` cannot be represented as a `bool`.  For your last example (with `+1`), try with (say) `+2` instead.  I think you'll get a different result. _For line 1 and 2 ... is there a rule for this?_ I would expect there to be, yes, but I'm no language lawyer so I'll turn that one over to the smart guys.

Comment: Ah, I see. With `+2` you get an ambiguous function call only because of the forwarded function call so that is the same error as in line 2. But, I still find it strange because `int` is implicitly convertible to e.g. `bool` and to `unsigned`, independent of the value. Of course these are template parameters and so constant expressions and the compiler can be *smart* but it is getting inconsistent from the type system point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-type template argument is required to be a *converted constant expression* of the template parameter's type.

A *converted constant expression* specifically does not allow for narrowing conversions, which in the case of constant expression evaluation between integral types means that the conversion is not allowed if it would change the numeric value.

This is specific to the *converted constant expression* requirement. If these were function parameter and argument, then implicit conversion of `-1` to `unsigned` would be allowed and it also has a well-defined result, although obviously not with the same numeric value of `-1`.

Therefore in `foo<true, -1, 0ul, 1ul, 2ul>();` the template which requires `unsigned` in that position for `-1` is indeed not viable as an overload candidate.

*Boolean conversions*, meaning conversions from other scalar types to `bool` are not listed in the list of conversions allowed for a *converted constant expression* at all (see [[expr.const]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#10)), which as far as I can tell should make the overload with `bool` in the first position non-viable for both `foo<-1, 0ul, 1ul, 3ul>();` and `foo<+1, 0ul, 1ul, 3ul>();`. I am not sure why the compilers consider the latter ambiguous anyway. According to the resolution of [CWG issue 1407](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1407) as not-a-defect, the conversion from `int` template argument to `bool` template parameter is indeed not allowed, but compilers are behaving non-conforming and seem to treat it like an integral type with range `0`/`1`.

I don't know what problem GCC <8 has. I guess it was just a bug that it considered the overload ambiguous.

Comment: For the `int` to `bool` conversion this means that 0 to `false` and 1 to `true` do not change the numeric value and are allowed conversions while all others would change the numeric value and are therefore disallowed?

Comment: @mpeschke Conversions to bool are actually not listed in the list of conversions allowed for a _converted constant expression_ at all, see https://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#10 and https://www.eel.is/c++draft/conv. I am not sure whether I am missing something or the compilers are not behaving correctly in that case.

Comment: @mpeschke Seems that there is really a disconnect between standard and implementations in this case, see [CWG issue 1407](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1407)

Comment: Thanks for the references. In fact now I am wondering again about line 1 and 2 because after the integer conversion from +1 `int` to `unsigned` which is an allowed conversion, the `bool true` needs to be converted to `int` which should not be allowed either..

Comment: @mpeschke `bool` to `int` is an _integral promotion_ and listed without restriction in the definition of _converted constant expression_ I linked.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @user17732522 completely explains the conversion behavior.

Here is a hack to achieve a default template parameter for the `bool` template parameter of the function:

```
template<bool b>
struct Dummy {};

template <int i, unsigned... us, bool b>
void foo(Dummy<b>) {}

template <int i, unsigned... us>
void foo() {return foo<i, us...>(Dummy<false>{});}

int main()
{
    foo<-1, 0ul, 1ul, 2ul>(Dummy<true>{});
    foo<+1, 0ul, 1ul, 2ul>(Dummy<true>{});
    foo<-1, 0ul, 1ul, 3ul>();
    foo<+1, 0ul, 1ul, 3ul>();
}
```